# SQL Job fails when SSIS packages run with Path containing hyphen "-"

Tags: sql-server, windows

I need to schedule a Job that runs multiple SSIS packages which reads data from multiple files.

File paths are like:

```
\\FilePath\uat-files\FileName.csv
```

So the Parameter values are like:

```
\\FilePath\uat-files\
```

The problem is that it interprets -files as an option:

> Option "-files\ /Par $Project::FilePath;"\FilePath\uat" is not valid.
> The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed

No matter if the paths are entered as Parameter Value of SSIS step configuration (1 - on pic below) (of SQL Job) or passed by Environment Variables (2).

[image: SQL Job - SSSI Step configuraiton]

Unfortunately I cannot change the folder name. Need to figure out how to schedule SSIS packages. I already tried with quotation marks ("parameterValue").

The problem seems to be solved when I trigger the SSIS package as SQL step and execute the package using SSISDB stored procedure with FilePath as one of parameter but It cannot be done that way.

How to escape minus/hyphen in this particular case?

Comment: Properly escaping values so they work on a command line is required and can be tricky depending on the language/script type which often requires it's own escaping of string literals. Show the code from your attempt.

Comment: The parameter values (the paths to the folders where the files are stored) are simply either given as Value of Parameter in Configuration tab of SSIS step in SQL Job (SQL Server Agent) or pass as Environment Variables. Will try to attach screen shot to description above. 

And yes, that's why I have tried to use " " to escape the hyphens. Same error still getting. How to escape them ?

Comment: Still haven't shown your code. Parameter values don't magically become command line arguments. Some expression or assignment does that along with it being used someplace.

Comment: I have Project Parameters in SSIS solution which are folder path like in my example "\\FilePath\uat-files\". Then on each SSIS package under this project I have variables that specify file pattern (i.e. FileName*.csv, FileName, etc) and both are used to build Variable ConnectionStringToEachFile, like  @[Project::FolderPath] +  @[User::FileName]. Then I use ConnectionStringToEachFile variable in expression of ConnectionManager of input file.

Comment: Any resolution?